# Creating a expressjs middleware that accepts parameters

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to create a middleware that can accept parameters. How can this be done?

example

```
app.get('/hasToBeAdmin', HasRole('Admin'), function(req,res){

})

HasRole = function(role, req, res, next){
   if(role != user.role){
      res.redirect('/NotInRole);
   }

   next();
}
```

Comment: Ha, you've asked my exact question for my exact scenario, but 6 years earlier. SO is awesome.

Comment: @aero exact same thing i was looking for :D

Comment: @aero 7 years later I'm looking for the same exact one :D

Comment: @aero 7+ years later I'm looking for the exact same thing!

Comment: @aero 8~ years later I'm looking for the exact same thing! \o/

Comment: @aero 9 years later I'm looking for the exact same thing! ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @aero another 9 years later, I'm looking for the exact same thing ‍

Comment: @aero 9 years later I'm looking for the same thing :)

Comment: @aero another 9 years later :)

Comment: @aero year 10 and I'm looking for this exact thing :D

Comment: @aero year 10 (: favorite site for sure.

Comment: @aera year 11 we are still on the grind

Comment: @aero chiming in for 11 years and still going strong!

Answer (score 210, accepted):

```
function HasRole(role) {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    if (role !== req.user.role) res.redirect(...);
    else next();
  }
}
```

I also want to make sure that I don't make multiple copies of the same function:

```
function HasRole(role) {
  return HasRole[role] || (HasRole[role] = function(req, res, next) {
    if (role !== req.user.role) res.redirect(...);
    else next();
  })
}
```

Comment: The second method caches parameters, which or may not be the desired behavior.

Comment: @Jonathan Ong, can you please explain the second definition of the function. What is happening there? I don't understand the following line 
 return HasRole[role] || (HasRole[role] = function(req, res, next) {

Comment: @JonathanOng could you please explain the second example a bit more for those not knowing the node that good? (including me). When can you get multiple copies of the same function and when this can cause problems? Thanks.

Comment: without caching, `app.get('/a', hasRole('admin'))` and `app.get('/b', hasRole('admin'))` would create a new closure for each `hasRole`. this doesn't matter too much realistically unless you have a really large application. i just code like this by default.

Comment: @Pier-LucGendreau what do you mean when you say the second method caches parameters? Does it mean that a new request could read the value of `req.user.role` from a previous request?

Comment: No, it does not mean that a new request could read the value of req.user.role from a previous request.

Personally I find it hard to read but pay attention to this line `return HasRole[role] || (HasRole[role] = function(...) { ... }` It means the function is created only once, which may be problematic if you attempt to use variables in the scope above the HasRole function

Comment: Doesn't the first solution create memory leaks? Also, what would be the TypeScript implementation of the second solution?

Answer (score 26):

```
app.get('/hasToBeAdmin', (req, res, next) => {
  hasRole(req, res, next, 'admin');
}, (req,res) => { 
    // regular route 
});

const hasRole = (req, res, next, role) => {
   if(role != user.role){
      res.redirect('/NotInRole');
   }
   next();
};
```

Comment: Good and simple idea. Middleware really is just a normal function. Why not pass other values to it. Please include req, res and next in the first function.

Comment: While code often speaks for itself, it's good to add some explanation to your code. This popped up in the review queue, as code-only answers tend to.

Comment: I was thinking of that approach before visiting SO, but I thought "Meh, there's surely a better way". After visiting I see that this really is the simplest, most effective way.

Answer (score 12):

I use this solution. I recieve a jwt token in body req, and get role information from there

```js
//roleMiddleware.js

const checkRole = role => {
    
    return (req, res, next) => {
        if (req.role == role) {
            console.log(`${role} role granted`)
            next()
        } else {
            res.status(401).send({ result: 'error', message: `No ${role} permission granted` })
        }
    }
}

module.exports = { checkRole }
```

So first I use auth middleware to know if is a valid user, and then the role middleware to know if user have access to the api route

```js
// router.js

router.post('/v1/something-protected', requireAuth, checkRole('commercial'), (req, res) => {
    // do what you want...
})
```

I hope to be useful

Comment: How does `checkRole` middleware receive `req` if it is not explicitly passed into it?

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively if you do not have too many cases or if role is NOT a string:

```js
function HasRole(role) {
  return function (req, res, next) {
    if (role !== req.user.role) res.redirect(/* ... */);
    else next();
  }
}

var middlware_hasRoleAdmin = HasRole('admin'); // define router only once

app.get('/hasToBeAdmin', middlware_hasRoleAdmin, function (req, res) {

})
```

Comment: elegant solution

Answer (score 3):

If you have various permissions levels you could structure them like this:

```
const LEVELS = Object.freeze({
  basic: 1,
  pro: 2,
  admin: 3
});

/**
 *  Check if user has the required permission level
 */
module.exports = (role) => {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    if (LEVELS[req.user.role] < LEVELS[role]) return res.status(401).end();
    return next();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since we are in 2021 why not using an ES6 syntax?... Using NodeJS v14.16.1 the example below works like a charm :-)

**With express routers**

```
const someFunc = ({ option1, option2 }) =>
 router.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
    
 // code
    
 next();
});

module.exports = someFunc;
```

**or**

```
const someFunc = ({ option1, option2 }) =>
     (req, res, next) => {
        
     // code
        
     next();
    };
    
 module.exports = someFunc;
```

... Then call it like:

```
const someFunc = require('./middlewares/someFunc.js');
app.use(someFunc({option1: 'test', option2: false ));
```

Answer (score 2):

After following documentation from [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html), I was able to solve this issue, I  made this middleware and passed the array of role_ids that were allowed to access the route

```
exports.authorize = function (roles) {
  return function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(roles)
    if (roles?.includes(req.user.role_id)) {
      return next()
    } else {
      return res.status(403).send({
        error: "Not Authorized to access this route"
      })
    }
  }
}
```

and called it in routes file like this

```
myRouter.get("/", authorize([USER_ROLES.OPERATOR]), getSomething);
```

if you are wondoring what user role is its just like an enum

```
const USER_ROLES = Object.freeze({
  ADMIN: 1,
  HOST: 2,
  OPERATOR: 3,
  LOCKER_ADMIN: 4,
  MERCHANT: 5,
  CUSTOMER: 6,
  COURIER: 7,
  ECOMMERCE: 8
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my simple solution for this. Basically we cannot pass arguments to middleware but using wrapper function we can achieve this.

```
const restrictTo = (...roles) => {
   return (req, res, next) => {
    // roles are : ['admin', 'user'], role : req.user.role
   if (!roles.includes(req.user.role)) // I am taking role from req.user you can get it from model
      {
       return new Error('You dont have permission to delete the tour', 404)
      }
   next();
  }
};
Call it like ...

router.delete(restrictTo('admin', 'user'), handler);
```