# How does this Node.js middleware work without arguments?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using a function that someone else wrote for `express` and `passport`, which defines the middleware(?) as follows:

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()){ 
        return next(); 
    }
    else{
        req.flash('error', 'You need to be logged in to access this page');
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

This function is used in the router as follows:

```
app.get('/page', isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
    // ...
});
```

What I don't understand is, shouldn't the function be called with parameters `req` and `res`? Maybe the callback `next` is not necessary since it's the next argument of `app.get`, but how does the function access `req` and `res`? I would expect it to be called as follows:

```
app.get('/page', isLoggedIn(req, res), function(req, res){
    // ...
});
```

How does it work without specifying the arguments?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any functions that you pass to `app.get()` or `app.use()` are automatically called with `req, res, next` passed to them.  That is how `app.get()` and `app.use()` are implemented.

To help you understand, this example:

```
app.get('/page', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.params.foo);
});
```

is functionally the same as this:

```
app.get('/page', myHandler);

function myHandler(req, res) {
    console.log(req.params.foo);
});
```

---

You do not want to do something like this:

```
app.get('/page', isLoggedIn(req, res), function(req, res){
    // ...
});
```

because here you're attempting to execute `isLoggedIn(req, res)` (when `req` and `res` are not yet defined) and then pass it's returned value to `app.get()`.  That is not what you want at all.  You need to pass a function reference to `app.get()` and it will supply the parameters when it calls the function.  Any time you put `()` after a function in Javascript, that means you want to execute it NOW.  But, if you just pass the function's name, then that is a function reference which can be stored and called later as desired.

This code example is analogous to this:

```
var result = isLoggedIn(req, res);

app.get('/page', result, function(req, res){
    // ...
});
```

Besides the fact that this would cause an error because `req` and `res` are not defined at program start time when this would execute, hopefully you can see that you don't want to execute `isLoggedIn()` now.  Instead, you just want to pass a function reference so Express can call it later.

Comment: Thanks! And good point about `req` and `res` not being present yet. So if I were to define my own middleware, it should always have those three parameters? What if I wanted to add another parameter? Anyways, this answers my question so I will accept it in a few minutes.

Comment: @jeff - You can't add your own parameters to middleware.  Middleware will get `(req, res, next)` as the arguments.  If you have a function you want to call that needs more arguments than that, then you create a standard middleware function with the three arguments and you call your other function from within that and pass your own function whatever arguments it needs.

Comment: Yes. I just found -I think- the same thing [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12737295/2483127).

Comment: @jeff - Yeah, that example is a little trickier - with a function returning a function.  You may not need to do that.  You may be able to just do `function(req, res, next) { myFunc(req, res, next, someOtherArg);}` as your middleware.

Answer (score 1):

In this code

```
app.get('/page', isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
    // ...
});
```

The `app.get` method is being called with three arguments:

1. the route to the page: `/page`
2. the middleware **function**
3. the request handler **function**

Basically, this code is telling the express framework that when a `GET` request is received for the `/page` path, then it should call two functions: first, the middleware function and second the handler function.

The important thing to note here is that it is the framework doing the work. The framework is going to call the middleware function, then it's going to call the handler function.

Answer (score 1):

> What I don't understand is, shouldn't the function be called with parameters req and res?

It **will be** called with these arguments, somewhere inside the `get` function. Suppose this is the simplified `get`, implemented as

```
// a super simple get that will expect a function
// and call the function with two arguments
function get( f ) {
    var res = 1, req = 1;
    f( res, req );
}
```

There are multiple ways of passing a function to `get`. For example, you pass an anonymous function

```
get( function( res, req ) {
   return res + req;
}
```

You can also pass a named function defined elsewhere

```
function isLoggedIn( res, req ) {
   return res + req;
}

get( isLoggedIn );
```

This however, is not what you'd expect:

```
get( isLoggedIn( res, req ) );
```

The problem here is that

```
isLoggedIn( res, req )
```

is no longer a function **declaration**. It is an **invocation** and the result of this invocation depends on what `res` and `req` are. With some luck, the invocation can even yield a number value, which means that `get` is no longer invoked with function as an argument but with the **result** of function invocation.

In short, to pass a named function to another function, you don't specify its arguments. The supposed syntax that would allow this doesn't even make sense because it would be indistinguishable from a syntax of actual function invocation (i.e. the value of the call).