# How return is getting parameters in this function

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I was looking on the web to comprehend how we can pass additional parameter to the middleware which is when I stumbled upon the following question: [Creating a expressjs middleware that accepts parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737148/creating-a-expressjs-middleware-that-accepts-parameters)

Here the correct answer have answered this

```
function HasRole(role) {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    if (role !== req.user.role) res.redirect(...);
    else next();
  }
}
```

for the following route 
`

```
app.get('/hasToBeAdmin', HasRole('Admin'), function(req,res){

})
```

also, I know that express passes `req, res, next` to the middleware.

Now, what I am trying comprehend is how can our return function have different parameter and how it receives those parameter when we are only passing `HasRole('Admin')` to the function. In technical terms, what is this known as so i can probably google and find more about it.

**update:** Consider this none node example, I have the following function

```
function foo(a,b,c) {
  return function (d, e, f) {
  }
}
```

How will I pass `d, e, f` to return in the above function?

Comment: It receives the arguments *when* it is called *by* whoever calls it…

Comment: The function `foo` is one that returns another function (the one with d, e and f as parameters). So, the return value of foo can be used as a regular function again

Comment: `foo(1,2,3)(4,5,6)`

Comment: Because of middleware, you will find everything in middleware like req, body, everything which will pass from client.

Answer (score 2):

`HasRole('Admin')` returns a function.

That function is immediately passed as the second argument to `app.get()` (and another function is passed as the third argument).

Those functions are passed arguments **when they are called**.

The code which calls them is not shown in your question (because you didn't write `app.get()`, it's part of Express, so you'd need to dig into the source code of Express to see it).

---

Functions in JS are first class objects. They can be passed around like any other value.

```js
function give_me_a_function () {
    return function (a, b, c) {
        console.log({ a, b, c });
    }
}

function call_a_function_with_args(a_function) {
    a_function(1, 2, 3);
}

const x = give_me_a_function();
call_a_function_with_args(x);
```