# How can I send parameter to middleware

Tags: node.js, express, ecmascript-6

I am using Express to build an app. In this application there have a `middleware` function where I am checking the JWT token..

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

    module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
        console.log('auth is calling dude!!')
        try {
            const token = req.headers.authorization;
            const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECREAT);
            req.userdata = decoded
            next();
        } catch (error) {
            return res.status(404).json({
                message: "Auth Failed",
                success: false,
            })
        }
    }
```

Now I want to check , is the logged user valid to access the api or not? for that I want to take a parameter (userType) on auth middleware and after decoding the JWT I want to compare the userType with decoded data user type ..

I am calling then auth middleware form route ..

```
router.get('/', Auth, CampaignController.getAllCampaign)
```

How can I pass the parameter from router and receive that on auth middleware?

Comment: perhaps you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737148/creating-a-expressjs-middleware-that-accepts-parameters)

Comment: No worries @Rabbani!

Comment: quit slimier .. but that solves my problem @SuleymanSah