# Registering Admin in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, security, rbac

What I am trying to do is that, there is some `Admin` who has all the access to routes and also some routes where only he is allowed. So, this is one part.
Now, my question arises is that how someone can become a Admin, like who is actually a Admin.
There are some articles online where they mention that "Give a `Role` property, that can be from { 'user' , 'admin' }". But there is nothing stopping a normal user from becoming a Admin. So, how top Organizations or any, implements the Admin part considering security and trust models ?

Answer (score 0):

So a user would sign up to your website using whatever you have. You would pass the JWT with the user identifier on each request to the API from the client as well as the session.

Your node.js API would have middleware to check if the user's session is valid and if the JWT is correct. `Website -> Node.js App -> Middleware -> Protected Api Route`. If you are using Express then you would call `next()` in your middleware function. If they are not authorized then you would use: `return res.status(403).send({message:"Not Authenticated"})`

### Middleware

Inside your middleware, you would want to use some caching such as `Redis` to reduce the load on your server. You would also want separate middleware to handle rate limiting(if you need it). Another method would be calling your database instead of storing the data in the JWT itself. You would check the database by searching for the user identifier in the JWT after verifying it. There's the possibility for sessions but you can just get the role from the database if you aren't doing that.

You would either use a number-based system as an enum. An example of one:

```
0 - No access
1 - User
2 - Admin
```

Each route would specify a value see: [Creating a expressjs middleware that accepts parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737148/creating-a-expressjs-middleware-that-accepts-parameters) on how to do it in Express. If the user role is smaller than the required role then refuse entry to the API route by sending a 403.

### Give a role

You would have an API route that would give roles to people. You would also set in your cache the user identifier's role as well as in the database. I would only allow setting a role by `roleNum - 1` as the max role that person can give. I would also either set a user as the super admin by the database itself or create a default user with the max role by default.

### Remove a role

You would have another API route that would set the role to 0 or 1(basically the role you want to give).

Comment: okay. so the main essence I am getting is that, to make someone a Admin we will directly make by changing the database. I am really confused in How to make someone a Admin ?

Comment: @rickster call the API route to update the role