# Create a routes-wide reusable MongoDB connection in Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am writing a small application. You could think of it like this:

```
Server
 -- Security
 -- Microservices
 -- Others
```

The server routes to each of those. Each of those routes uses a different MongoDB database (same server).

I don't find the way to make a single, reusable connection to MongoDB server, that could be reused each route.

For example:

```
//server.js
//import  modules etc

async function connectDB(){
const uri = process.env.MONGOURI;
const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
useNewUrlParser: true,
useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

return (await client.connect());
}
```

But I can not pass the returned client to any route, as the routes take no parameters:

```
//server.js
import security from "./security";

async function run() {
// security
app.use("security", security) //cant pass mongo client
```

If I write the client in the routes themselves:

```
//security.js
  router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
    const database = await connectDB()
    const users = database.collection("users");
```

I will have to run `connectDB()` to each route.

### Question

- Is there a way to create a connection in the server.js that will be reused in other routes?

Comment: You can pass arguments to middleware. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737148/creating-a-expressjs-middleware-that-accepts-parameters

Comment: that won't work if you try it, not with asyncs @code

Comment: Create the connection on application start. By the time and routes are hit, the day database will have already connected.

Comment: well thought. I will try @code